# Why css don't loaded in django?

Tags: css, django

I encountered a problem. Just my .html, the css files not loaded,even I write the absolute path which can be visited from the browser as follows:

```
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Could anyone please help me?

**My PyCharm project location:    E:\workspaces\workspace-py\python-test

django project relative lication:  \django\djangotest**

\template\base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}"/>
```

\static\css\bootstrap.min.css

\djangotest\settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out after saw the source code of the "admin" app.
The tag of "block stylesheet" is needed.

```
    {% block stylesheet %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}"/>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed addiing static urls in your urls.py.

for your reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Thank u for your advice.   I tried, but nothing changed.  There is still no request of the css file in my "Network" of Chrome .

Comment: Check your page source, what your django templates rendered. Is there your links of css.